# PROCEDURE ignorando update - PL-SQL

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Fiz o seguinte código:

```
CREATE
OR
replace noneditionable
PROCEDURE comissao
IS
BEGIN
  FOR v_linha IN
  (
            SELECT    p.codvendedor     AS codvend,
                      p.comissao        AS comissao,
                      SUM(f.valortotal) AS quant
            FROM      vendedor p
            left join venda f
            ON        p.codvendedor = f.codvendedor
            GROUP BY  p.codvendedor,
                      p.comissao)
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      UPDATE vendedor
      SET    valor = v_linha.quant * (v_linha.comissao/100)
      WHERE  vendedor.codvendedor = vlinha.codvend;
    END;
   END LOOP;
END comissao;
```

O SQL DEVELOPER está apresentando o erro: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse UPDATE está errado?.

Comment: Vlinha <> v_linha ...

Comment: Muito obrigado. Errei feio demais nessa.

Comment: :) faz parte ...